# get request failing while using grails-json-rest-api-plugin

Tags: json, grails, grails-plugin

class ActionType {

```
static expose = 'action-type'

String name
String description

static constraints = {
    name blank: false, unique: true
}
```

static mapping = {
    id generator: 'increment', column : 'id'
  }
}

On hitting http://localhost:8090/api/v1.0/action-type

This is giving following error :

HTTP CODE : 500

response: {
    "success": false,
    "message": "Entity null not found"
}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without *v1.0*? Also you need to make sure that your 'context' is correct. In general, if your app is called 'foo', then grails will give you a localhost api similar to

`http://localhost:8090/foo`

so the way to use the plugin is

`http://localhost:8090/foo/api/action-type`

(which will give you a list of action-type(s) that are currently in your db)

Documentation is [here](https://grails.org/plugin/json-rest-api).

Comment: I defined in my Config.groovy frollowing line grails.'json-rest-api'.root = '/api/v1.0'